# How I can handle the multiple transactions

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I have a c# rest service which is distributed among across different servers. In the service I have a balance check for the incoming request amount and if balance is there, we proceed and create the transaction.

```
if(txnamount> balamount){
 // return
}
else{
//create txn
}
```

The balance amount is calculated using the previous txn amounts. If bulk request comes in quick session, balance check condition fails when previous txn amount is not reduced from the balance. How to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fundamental limit of computer systems.

On a single system it is fairly trivial since you have locks built into the language and operating system.

For multiple systems the simple answer is to use a database and let it deal with locking etc. Databases are built specifically to deal with this kind of problem. Just open a transaction and do your operation inside the transaction. Or keep a version value on each row and fail commits if the version value has been changed between the read and write.

On a more fundamental level you need to ensure exclusive access. This could be done by a central authority to manage access (like a database). Or you could assign values to specific machines, so all requests for that value need to be run on that machine ([like a database shard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture))). Or you could use [two phase locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking). This is a topic you could probably spend your entire career on if you want to go really deep.

Comment: Balance is calculated using different logics using SP. The value is not stored in a table.

Comment: @ShibinMathew you can view the transaction log of a database as being the "real database", with the tables of values only being cached values of the transaction log. So it is not clear to me why your use case could not be modeled using standard database operations. Ofc, you do not *need* to use a DB, but you will likely need to replicate much of the functionality provided by one.

Comment: Is there any way to queue from the programing side

Comment: @ShibinMathew Any kind of distributed and consistent queue will still have to solve the exclusive access problem. There are probably some products out there that for that, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . But it will likely be far simpler to use some kind of centralized queue. Providing synchronization in distributed systems is *hard*.

Comment: @ShibinMathew also, issues like this should be considered in the initial design of the system. You cannot make a distributed system without considering what synchronization you need and how it will affect scaling and performance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with something that requires Event sourcing technic, you need some sort of immutable state especially when dealing with financial problems